# HarfBuzz getting started

Tags: fonts, freetype, text-rendering, harfbuzz

I cannot find the guide to get started with using HarfBuzz in my own app.

I looked here:

http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/

This seems to be the official page of HarfBuzz.

I looked over Download, Building and Development sections. But I must be overlooking something.

Answer (score 3):

Some good and simple examples are listed on [Harfbuzz wiki](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/wiki#user-examples), [1](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/blob/master/util/shape-consumer.hh), [2](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/blob/master/util/view-cairo.hh)

I suggest you a higher level library, [Pango](http://www.pango.org/) if you need layout things like line wrap and I guess you would find better [doucmentation for it](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/) than HarfBuzz itself.

You may have a look at [State of Text Rendering](http://behdad.org/text/) also.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue and was looking for the instructions. Finally I found at below link. It includes Android sample app with build instructions and all. Enjoy :
[Indic-text-renderer](https://code.google.com/p/indic-text-renderer/)

Answer (score 3):

I found harfbuzz html docs here
http://fossies.org/linux/harfbuzz/docs/html/index.html

Comment: Question is off-tpic, and this answer is only a link, but this could be the answer. thanks a lot @none53

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a post to the harfbuzz mailing list with some (non working) example code [here](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/harfbuzz/2008-March/000220.html); however, it's from 2008.

It also looks like the source code itself contains some [documentation](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/tree/master/docs/reference), although I think it needs to be generated via the makefile.