# Open type font issue

Tags: cairo, pango, opentype, harfbuzz

Basically,this is a problem of displaying a minority language.

Let me make it brief:

1. I've been trying to make my Opentype font(which has some features in it) work properly on non-windows(on windows, it works fine) platforms(Android ,iOS etc.).
2. What I'm truly dealing with is a problem as complicated as displaying Arabic language(including glyph substitution,shaping etc.).
3. I simply want to display the characters properly in my own software,because system wide support may be even more complicated for me to achieve.
4. I checked out ICU, Pango, Harfbuzz... and finally decided to work on Pango. [See Pango ScriptGallery](http://www.pango.org/ScriptGallery).

So,here's the questions:

1.Can I use pango as a supportive module in my project to display that language? I tried to install Pango on ubuntu,came with no success.I'm pretty confused now because Pango is related to harfbuzz,cairo,freetype,fontconfig blabla when installing.
2.If can't, is there any other light-weight ways to achieve that ?

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: For 2, is your problem "as complicated as", or are you literally doing Arabic and getting text shaped correct is the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which programming language do you use or you should use?

As you question tags, you may have a look at [this](http://marc.info/?l=cairo&m=121692252128947) (the second code), just do a `sudo apt-get install python-gtk2` for it, [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302458/python-issues-with-pango-and-pangocairo?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

A lightweight solution would be using HarfBuzz [directly](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/wiki#user-examples).

Comment: thank you Byagowi, I thought about using HarfBuzz directly but didn't get a clue on how to use that,and I don't know what HarfBuzz is really capable of. If it can be used to display the language vertically ? or if I have to make my text rendered in vertical direction through text editor? I want to write a software both on android an ios devices,using native code.So I have to worry about if  there would be any problem implementing HarfBuzz functionality in my project ? As to language,I would prefer C/C++.

Comment: HarfBuzz takes some text characters from same script and language (and dirctionaliity, ltr, rtl) and gives you correspond glyphs positions. You know, if adopting one of examples here https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/wiki#user-examples is not just simple task for you (that is just beginning about rendering of text), I would say it is better to solve you problem in another way, http://stackoverflow.com/a/23395621/1414809

Comment: so,harfbuzz will just take the unicode point and gives back the correct glyph's id or image or something back to text-renderer like freetype,and then text-renderer will do all the remaining work,is that right? If I have to use harfbuzz as a library in my app,then I have to dive into some text-renderer and implement one of my own?

Comment: just as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317181/harfbuzz-hello-world),I don't know how to use or even test this functionality. If I have to build the HarfBuzz and then write a program to use it as a library for testing? All I want now is to get this thing work and see my font displaying correctly. Thank you so much.

Comment: From reading the original question and your comments here again, I would say simply testing with a browser (or a embedded browser you app) is easiest way for improving your font.